# how to install tp link wn725n wifi usb adapter on ubuntu Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

i have a usb wifi adapter Tp-Link model: wn725n 
it works very well on windows but i can't find any drivers for linux/ubuntu i tried everything online but nothing work so far

i'm using

Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

3.19.0-28-generic

laptop: hp probook 4540s

can you please help me install this adapter?

Answer (score 15):

I found the solution. I installed the driver for the usb wifi adapter successfully using the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu
cd rtl8188eu
make all
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8188eu.ko
```

and then I used the following command:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

to get the internal wifi driver file name and then add it to blacklist

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist
```

and add the following line to the end of the file:

```
blacklist xxxxx
```

where `xxxx` is the internal wifi driver file name.

Restart and Ubuntu should now work with the usb adapter.

Note: if your internal wifi is fine then you don't need to blacklist it, i only did that because it was tuened off by hardware switch and doesn't want to turn on again and it turns off the usb wifi as well so i had to blacklist it.

Comment: good that you posted it.

Comment: What was the internal wifi driver name?

Comment: in Alaa's solution from beginning, between lines `git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu` and `make all` should be added: `cd rtl8188eu`

Comment: it was /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf in my case (editing /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist didn't affect nothing)

Comment: Great answer! I didn't had an internal wifi driver. So using `sudo lshw -C network` displayed me only my ethernet drivers, no wifi driver - so i skipped the last few steps and it worked

Comment: Just couple of updates for me on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, `sudo modprobe 8188eu.ko` becomes `sudo modprobe 8188eu` and `sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` becomes `sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`. Worked for me.

Comment: For newer kernels, consider this driver instead github.com/clnhub/rtl8192eu-linux. At least for my machine, it is many times way faster.

Comment: how to know internal wifi driver name? is it the same as logical name from `lshw -C network` ?

Answer (score 7):

This device worked out of the box for me with Xubuntu 16.04.01 (32-bit). No need to manually install any drivers or even do anything at all. If it doesn't work immediately, do a reboot. It works for me without any tinkering or installation of anything at all.

Please note that I had the dongle plugged in even as I booted from the live CD and installed Xubuntu.

Comment: Second this. I plugged it in and restarted. Done!

Comment: dongle V1 or V2?

Comment: @marcolopes Don't remember. Don't have it anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to install without installing the rtl8188eu driver mentioned in other answer. My installation worked pretty fine by downloading the [TL-WN725N driver from the official TPLink website](http://www.tp-link.com/il/download/TL-WN725N.html#Driver) and firing the following commands as instructed in their installation manual :

```
sudo make
sudo make install
```

I ran the above commands by cd'ing into the `Driver` folder downloaded in driver's archive file

EDIT: in newer kernel versions this solution does not work

Answer (score 4):

Actually there are 2 different revision of this **tl-wn725n** wifi adapter, the **v1** and the **v2** which have different chipsets.

### How to recognize them?

The [tp-link](http://www.tp-link.com/il/faq-46.html) website say that is possible to recognize them by the FCCID (labeled on the adapter).

If your FCCID terminates with **v2** then is the second revision, which use the **RTL8188EUS** Realtek chipset.

Otherwise if your FCCID terminates with **v1** (or you can't find a hardware version) it is the first revision, based on the Realtek **RTL8188CUS** chipset.

### Where do i find the driver?

For the v2 version on the tp-link website : [here](http://www.tp-link.com/il/download/TL-WN725N_V2.html)

For the v1 version [here](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#2772) (from realtek) , or [here](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/rtl819x)

### More info:

https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN725N_v1

Answer (score 2):

I connected my HP laptop with internet using USB tethering to my mobile and Following are the commands that worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git
cd rtl8188eu/
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8188eu
sudo reboot
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS 64-bit and **TP-Link 150Mbps Wireless N Nano USB Adapter TL-WN725N**

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me on Debian 10 buster to get it working. I did not have to reboot, but simply unplug and plug back in the usb adapter and it started working right away and I connected to wifi network.