# TP Link WN725N driver for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS running kernel 4.4

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04, kernel

I'm currently running Ubuntu 14.04.3 with kernel version 3.19.0-25-generic and use the TP Link WN725N for Wi-fi.

I followed this guide for the driver installation otherwise I'd get barely any signal:

[how to install tp link wn725n wifi usb adapter on ubuntu Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678134/how-to-install-tp-link-wn725n-wifi-usb-adapter-on-ubuntu-ubuntu-14-04-3-lts)

I installed 16.04 with kernel 4.4 a week ago but the adapter didn't work out of the box so I followed the above method again but it didn't work. I was, like before, barely getting any signal.

Any way to get the drivers working for kernel 4.4?

EDIT: Output of lsusb as requested:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b3c8 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I've posted the output

Comment: Hold on, I will check the code.

Comment: Are you asking about a USB or an internal PCI adapter? If it is about USB, then post output of `lsusb`.

Comment: Updated with lsusb output

Comment: It is rtl8192cu. I did not make a driver in PPA for 16.04 yet.

Comment: Any other sources I could get it from? Or is it in the works?

Comment: Search for `rtl8192cu` for 16.04. I will do it sometime.

Comment: You can try this deb. https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/rtl8192cu-dkms_0.2_all.deb I do not know if it needs some patching for kernel 4.4

Comment: But do not forget to disable secure boot if you have UEFI. 3rd party drivers are not loaded any more with SB on.

Comment: FWIW I think the WN725N 0bda:8179 is the rtl8188eu chipset. Out of the box for me, Ubuntu 16.04 is using the r8188eu driver and it seems to work. [This post](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/reserve-7#TOC-Realtek-RTL8188EU-chipset-0bda:8179-) claims that the low signal strength is just a display issue. The device doesn't show up in `iw dev` though and can't be configured for hostapd. With earlier kernels, I installed from [TP-Link's source](http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TL-WN725N.html#Driver). But it says it only supports up to 3.19.3.

Answer (score 0):

try the following steps, it worked for me -

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu
cd rtl8188eu  
make all  
sudo make install  
sudo insmod 8188eu.ko
```