# Ubuntu 20.04 TP-LINK TL-WN725N Nano USB Wireless N adapter issue

Tags: networking, drivers

I've successfully compiled and installed the drivers as following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu
cd rtl8188eu
make all
sudo make install
sudo insmod 8188eu.ko
```

However, when I try to load it I get this error:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlx5ca6e641663d
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlx5ca6e641663d disabled_11b_rates=0
wlx5ca6e641663d: Failed to initialize driver interface
```

My */etc/wpa_supplicant.conf* file looks fine:

```
network={
    ssid="VVV"
    #psk="password"
  psk=8d10e65f37d67d5f507fffabaa94dcb09855739486e4462021ac3d49b40a7e1b
}
```

What else should I try?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to install tp link wn725n wifi usb adapter on ubuntu Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678134/how-to-install-tp-link-wn725n-wifi-usb-adapter-on-ubuntu-ubuntu-14-04-3-lts)

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://github.com/sensepost/mana/issues/13 Why not simply use Network Manager instead of a wpasupplicant command? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.