# How can I setup the TL-WN725N Nano USB Adapter's drivers on Ubuntu 23.10 with kernel version 6.5.0-25-generic?

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, kernel

I have just bought the TL-WN725N Nano USB Adapter for my Ubuntu laptop. Still, to my disappointment, this USB adapter doesn't have any drivers beyond kernel version 4.x, which also goes for the third-party drivers for this hardware. So instead of returning this straight away I wanted to check if I missed something and if there is a driver for this USB adapter which supports Linux kernel 6 and above on Ubuntu. Also, I've already tried most of the third-party drivers and the official drivers and so far all of them gave me "make errors" due to kernel incompatibility. Please advise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to install tp link wn725n wifi usb adapter on ubuntu Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678134/how-to-install-tp-link-wn725n-wifi-usb-adapter-on-ubuntu-ubuntu-14-04-3-lts)